Docker coturn gives ERROR: You cannot define external IP more than once in the configuration even when only 1 ip is specified in config
I followed the documentation from
https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/docker/coturn/README.md to set up coturn on docker on my windows server. It has a public ip address. Every time i start the sever, i get the error "You cannot define external IP more than once in the configuration". I am very sure my config file is correct and i have checked the docker environment variable too but I dont know why this error occurs.
I tried using the -e DETECT_EXTERNAL_IP=yes but my coturn server remains unreachable and i keep getting error 701 on trickle ice and my webrtc application doesnt work. Im not sure what im doing wrong. I have opened TCP and UDP port 3478 for both inbound and outbound rules on my windows firewall.
config file:

listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=5349
external-ip=<my_public_ip_address>
lt-cred-mech
realm=<my_realm>
user=<my_username>:<my_password>
#log-file=/tmp/turnserver.log
#simple-log
cli-password=<my_password>
#cert=/etc/turn_server_cert.pem
#pkey=/etc/turn_server_pkey.pem



I tried removing external ip from the config file and using -e DETECT_EXTERNAL_IP=yes but that did not work.
